# Complex Java Command Line Parameterization

Tags: java, command-line-interface

I am trying to find the best solution to make my Java application configurable over the command line. The issue I am facing is that I need to configure complex nested structures.

### Example

Consider the following structure (words starting with a capital are classes, indenting notates attributes)

- InterfaceOptimizer

  - AbstractProblem

    - dimension
  - populationSize
  - numberOfRuns

The first thing I need to select from the command line is a class that implements `InterfaceOptimizer` (e.g. `java App -O SomeOptimizer`). The next thing to select would be the `AbstractProblem` which by itself takes another parameter `dimension` (e.g. `java App -O SomeOptimizer -- -P ConcreteProblem`.

The issue here is that some parameters are parameters for a specific class and depend on what parameter was first given. ConcreteProblem might take different parameters than OtherProblem.

### Tested Libraries

I tested [args4j](http://args4j.kohsuke.org) and [commons-cli](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/), but those both fail when trying to do what I need.

WEKA (a popular machine learning tool) seems to have implemented [a solution](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Primer) for this problem, but it basically requires each class to implement it's own CLI parser (and they seem to have issues with consistency).

Is there any good solution (existing library?) to this problem? What would be the recommended pattern be to solve this?

Comment: I don't know about easy, but you could create a `LL(*)` grammar and then use [ANTLR](http://antlr.org/).

Comment: We used to solve complex parameterlists for commandlinetools by using a config-file. In your case I would consider to use xml since you have a hierarchical structure. This solution is also more convenient for the user - compared to editing a complex parameter at the commandline and repeating this several times if you make mistakes ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure that there is an easy solution to your problem.  I've solved this problem in the past using a mixture of carefully defined interfaces and/or abstract superclasses and the Reflection API.  This allows you to bind parameters to method signatures.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: Interesting, but I think the LL(*) would just allow me to implement a generic CLI parser and not one that knows about the specific class implementations/parameters.

Comment: @treeno: Very true - but sadly I need a CLI here.

Comment: @Mathias: I guess optimally I want to annotate configurable attributes and generate a list of parameters with Reflection (I'm doing that for the first level already). I'm just not sure about how to represent that on the command line.

Comment: Actually, that's just the parser... you're implementation can leverage the generator stage (or more likely, use an evaluator)! :)

Comment: @halfdan: I confess that while the code I was referring to is CLI-based, the input files proper that describe the class configuration are all in XML (hence my upvote of the comment by @treeno).  Since robust XML parsing (with XPath, even!) got rolled into the official API, dealing with XML has become quite painless.

Comment: @halfdan: Oh... sorry, didN't understand that....

Comment: @halfdan: could you explain why you are forced to use CLI? Maybe you are saying it already, but I'm not shure about that.

Comment: @treeno, I'm doing meta optimization - so basically trying to find the best configuration for a given problem. The meta optimization tool I am using needs to call my application over the command line.

Comment: @halfdan, Ah, I understand... your optimization tool cannot write the parameter to a file... is the format of the commandline parameter also fixed?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're probably going to have to just write the code that selects the right classes. After that, you can use reflection to put the values into the objects and/or validate that the command line options are appropriate. Annotations would help you out tremendously here, because you could use that to help drive the reflection engine, as well as for generating documentation e.g. command line help.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, but this looks a lot like deserializing an object graph to me.
Java has built-in serialization/deserialization of object. E.g. to construct an object from an XML file:

```
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("config.xml"));
XMLDecoder d = new XMLDecoder(is);
InterfaceOptimizer obj = (InterfaceOptimizer)d.readObject();
```

To get an initial config file (as a starting point that you could manually alter), you could create the object programmatically, then dump it to an XML file using this:

```
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File("config.xml"));
XMLEncoder e = new XMLEncoder(os);
e.writeObject(myOptimizerObject);
```

You would then have to pass only the config file on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how this CLI is very complex, unless I didn't understand fully. You want

```
java X classname problem dimension population numberruns
```

Now, even if the part

```
classname problem dimension
```

or just

```
problem dimension
```

can be repeated, it is quite easy:

- First, take the population and numberofruns from the end and check
  for validity.
- Check if the remaining arguments are a multiple of 3 (assuming
  `classname problem dimension` can be repeated).
- For each 3 tuple of arguments, resolve and load the class, check if
  it accepts the given problem, and check the dimension argument. A
  simple way to do this would be to just call the constructor or some
  initialization code of that class, like so:

Code (to be refined):

```
try {
    IOptimizer io = (IOptimizer) Class.forName(args[n]).newInstance();
    io.init(args[n+1], args[n+2]);
}
catch (ClassNotFoundException ...) { ... }
catch (ClassCastException ...) { ... }
catch (InvalidArgumentException ...) { ... }
```

Note that if some Problem needs more than one paramter, you can implment like so:

```
 java X classname problem3 a,b,c population numbers
```

and then you can split the dimension parameter in the init() method.